# Two usages related to "with"

Tags: prepositions

OALD gives several examples in the entry of ["with"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/with)：

> **With these students** it's pronunciation that's the problem. #6

Is it a restricted usage? Why not use "to" or "for" instead?

> She acted **with a touring company** for three years. #14

Again, is it a restricted usage? Would "for" or "in" be acceptable in this example? Any nuances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, the difference between *with* and *to* or *for* is a matter of perspective: *for* or *to* implies that the problem is something the students must deal with, while *with* implies that the focus is on the problem as it affects someone other than the students—their teacher, for instance.

- If I have a problem *with* something it is a problem *to* or *for* me.

In the second example, the nuance is one of professional delicacy. Speaking of a theatre *company* usually does not address the enterprise as a business entity but as an ensemble of collaborative artists; in this context the actor does not act *for* the company (which would imply the business relationship of receiving a wage for services rendered) or *in* the company (which would imply pursuing distinct activities within an organization) but *with* it, collaborating with her colleagues.

Comment: Simple and understandable. But one thing, in the first sentence, no *comma* is used. Don't you think using it would make the sentence more understandable? To be frank, this structure of sentence does not seem in flow.

Comment: Thx a lot. Having been learning in this site, I have made a great progress with my English. Here "company” has the meaning of a group of people together, as in a pleasant evening in the company of friends. It does not refer to a business entity.

Comment: Btw, is the first usage common? Can it collocate with any verbs or nouns in a sentence? @StoneyB

Comment: @MaulikV With such brief phrases I see no need for a comma. But I'm not fond of heavy punctuation.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng It's perfectly ordinary. I'm not sure what scope of "any"  you have in mind.

Comment: 1.Is this usage always interchangeable with "as far as someone/something is concerned"? 2.You say **With such brief phrases** I see no need for a comma. Is it the same usage as my example? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng 1. No. It is usually contrastive: "with these X this is true", as opposed to "with those X that is true". 2. Yes.

Comment: So intuitive. Usage is more difficult to figure out than meaning.

Comment: Btw, I have a problem with something. Here "with something" modifies "a problem" or the whole sentence? Any interest in answering another of my questions? The modifying problem of prep phrases is just like a splinter in my mind. @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng It's a non-obligatory complement to *problem*.

Comment: In retrospect, I think the first example could be interpreted as "the teachers or anyone involved think that pronunciation is the problem they have to address for their students." or "the teachers have a problem with the students, who have difficulty in pronouncing English words." Right? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB Basically, yes.